# Bats, bees and nectar

Tags: botany

I have been thinking about this for a long time and your thoughts would really help. Since it's known that bats spread Covid 19, I studied more about places that they may have contacted. The first place that I came across was how they feed. Bats usually feed on nectar, now say that the bat is tested positive for covid 19. This may lead in others animals like bees getting their nectar contaminated. Now when these bees use the nectar to produce honey, and then the beekeepers collect the honey.
This may cause us humans getting positive for covid 19 when we eat honey. So why haven't we already tested positive for covid a long time back? It would be great if you can help me out over here.

Pardon my English, for it's my second language.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of incorrect assumptions here, including the basic premise of your question: bats absolutely do not spread COVID-19. This is a misunderstanding that has unfortunately gained a lot of traction amid the pandemic hysteria, and one that only serves to deepen the public's mistrust of bats and encourage people to harm or kill wildlife that pose no threat to anyone.

It's true that SARS-CoV-2 is similar to other bat coronaviruses, and it's not implausible that it could have originated there, but that's literally all we know at this point - we haven't even definitively established the true origin of the virus, much less unraveled the mystery of how it spread to humans.

What is clear, though, is that it's not being spread by bats. If nothing else, the rampant speculation about possible intermediate hosts suggests that it didn't come about merely as a result of direct contact between humans and bats, but through a much more circuitous pathway involving a specific combination of hosts and conditions that favored the jump to humans. Going beyond that, the idea that nectar-feeding bats could somehow "contaminate" the flowers, and that this in turn could somehow lead to live viruses showing up in honey produced by bees that visited those flowers, is mistaken on several levels.

You might be interested in this article, which gives an overview of what we currently know about the virus' origins: https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-01449-8.

In short, there are a lot of things to be concerned about when it comes to the spread of the pandemic, but one thing you definitely don't need to worry about is the possibility of contracting SARS-CoV-2 from bat-pollinated flowers.